# Why routes are not added $router.addRoutes?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Why routes are not added $ router.addRoutes?
I tried everything I can not

```
async loadMenu() {
        try{
            let res = await this.$http.get('/menu')
            this.menuItems = res.data
            res.data.forEach((e) => {
                this.$router.addRoutes([
                    {
                        path: /${e.url},
                        name: ${e.name},
                        component: require(`${e.compURL}`)
                    },
                ])
                console.log(e)
            })
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    },
```

I can not understand why not add dynamic routes?
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
const router = new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home,
            meta: {
                title: 'EHZ',
                layout: 'default-layout',
                catId: 1
            }
        },
    ],
    mode: 'history',
    // base: locale,
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth) { 

            Vue.axios.post('/auth/token')
                .then((res) => {
                    if ( res.status === 200 )
                        next()
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    store.dispatch('logout')
                    next({ path: '/auth/login'})
                })
    }
    else {
        next()
    }
})

export default router;
```

I added the code from the router.js. 
Something else needs to be shown?

---

I added a picture that I get in **res.data**

[image res.data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asdLT.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Let us know What error are you getting in the console? The path and name is expected to be `string` hence it should be `path: `/${e.url}`` and `name: `${e.name}`,`

Comment: no errors, empty

Comment: Instead of `console.log(e)`, replace it with "this.$router.push({path: `/${e.url}`);" and check if it is routing to the new page or not

Comment: Go to page works, but page is empty

Comment: that means routes are dynamically added. you need to add details inside your component. Please remove below answer as it confused other people.

Comment: I do not know what to add inside the component?
Since yesterday, I do not understand.
Deleted, sorry

Comment: this line and so works 
`this.$router.push({path: "./About.vue"})`
without this code
`
this.$router.push({path: "./About.vue"})

                this.$router.addRoutes([
                    {
                        path: /${e.url},
                        name: ${e.name},
                        component: require(`${e.compURL}`)
                    },
                ])
`

Comment: Look at the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/2or5g649/ I am creating & loading `Foo1` component dynamically

Comment: Do you have component URL properly in `${e.compURL}`

Comment: Yes there is "./About.vue" "./Video.vue" ...

Comment: Check the path properly. It will definitely load.

Comment: they are in the current folder, the path specified is correct

Comment: Then It must navigate to the correct page. Add your all code in above question then.

Comment: I did not understand what code to add? I showed the code above

Comment: Is there anyone else to help on this issue?

Comment: I need to create dynamic **routes [{...}]** and components, without an event button

Comment: What you're getting inside `res.data` is important in here. Can you add it the question? I will create a working version for you

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I added a picture to the question

Comment: In the res.data I get data for the route and menu

Comment: **varit05**, 
You wrote that can help with code?! Can't?

Comment: I've created a sample app. Facing some issues. I will post once it's done!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can achieve it as per below

Inside header.vue file

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    <div v-for="menu in dynamic" :key="menu.path">
      <router-link :to="menu.path">{{menu.name}}</router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import About from "@/components/About";
import Contact from "@/components/Contact";
export default {
  name: "Header",
  data: function() {
    return {
      msg: "Header Component!",
      dynamic: [
        {
          name: "About",
          component: "About",
          path: "/about"
        },
        {
          name: "Contact",
          component: "Contact",
          path: "/contact"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  created() {
    console.log("inside created");
    const routes = this.routerFormat(this.dynamic);
    console.log("routes ", routes);
    this.$router.addRoutes(routes);
  },
  methods: {
    routerFormat: function rFormat(routers) {
      console.log("inside routerFormat");
      if (!(routers instanceof Array)) {
        return false;
      }
      let fmRouters = [];
      routers.forEach(router => {
        let { path = "/404", component = "Error", name, children } = router;
        path = path || "";
        component = component || "Error";
        if (children && children instanceof Array) {
          children = rFormat(children);
        }
        console.log("component", component);
        let fmRouter = {
          path: path,
          component: About, // Import about page in the top
          //component: () => import(`./${name}.vue`).then(m => m),
          name: name,
          children: children
        };
        console.log(fmRouter);
        fmRouters.push(fmRouter);
      });
      console.log("fmRouters", fmRouters);
      return fmRouters;
    },
    addRoutes() {}
  }
};
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the example.
I can't configure something yet

Comment: Inside your axios success, you need to call a function from created method above and let routerFormat be the method. Make sure you add router-link in the template.

Comment: Did everything as you do.
I follow the link, I get empty page.
https://ibb.co/F6nn2rh

Comment: what do you have in your `about.vue` template

Comment: Can you try `component: About,` instead of `component: () => import(`./${name}.vue`).then(m => m),` and import about component above anc check

Comment: I did not quite understand where to insert "About.vue"?

Comment: There everything is statically loaded, and I load dynamically

Comment: For example, I loaded statically, There is an issue with path when Loading with Codesandbox.io That is why I am not able to make it workable except statically

Comment: Tomorrow I will try to load in the **codesandbox**, if I can, as I have done

Comment: Could not be done in the **codesandbox**, because did not find the terminal

Comment: So it was not possible to make the page appear in your code.

Comment: Download same code and run it locally and check. The issue in the console is because of Codesandbox

Comment: error on **component: () => import (`$ {router.compURL}`)**

Comment: Well, this isn't working, then can tell, if I add in admin panel a category, I assign a route and a component?
Can you tell me something?